# UML Class Diagram: Employee Manager relationship scenarios

Tags: oop, uml

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to model a certain scenario as a UML design class diagram.

Suppose I have the following situation:
I have an employee called X who is the CEO of the company.
A, B and C reports to X and U,V reports to A.

According to me, there should be an Interface called IEmployee which should have employee's name, designation and empNo.
Employee class should implement this IEmployee.
Manager class should implement Employee.

```
interface IEmployee
{
}
class Employee: IEmployee
{
}
class Manager: Employee
{
}
```

is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please adapt the title of your question, because it does not summarize what you ask.

Comment: Why do you think you need interface IEmployee? What do you mean by "more efficient"? Efficient in terms of design effort?

Comment: By more efficient I meant, is there any better way in terms of SOLID principals. @www.admiraalit.nl

Comment: With the information you gave us so far, there is no need to have interface IEmployee. Do you need just a diagram showing the classes or do you also want to show the instances A, B, C, U, V and X on the diagram? Do you want to have the 'reports to'-relationship displayed in the diagram?

Comment: Go through each SOLID principle and establish (think about) whether and how that principle applies to your design. You may need to know more about each class - or the intent of them - to be able to determine this. For example, Single Responsibility would depend on what you want to do with each of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you think *SOLID principals* should be, but your diagram would look like this:

[image]

`Employee` implements (realizes) `IEmployee` and `Manager` specializes `Employee`.

Comment: Maybe Anupriya would also like to see an assocation for '... reports to ...'.